# multiple values in like query mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
<?php 
$agenti = $_GET['agenti'];
$agen = array();
if (is_array($agenti)) {foreach($agenti as $val) { $agen[] = "ch.employeename LIKE '" . $val . "'"; }} else {$agen[] = 'true';}

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT distinct ch.employeename, ch.customername, 
                                       ch.customerowner, ch.QuestionnaireName, ch.parentgroupname,
                                       ch.groupname, ch.visitdate from chestionare ch
                                    WHERE ch.visitdate >= '".$_GET['from']."' AND ch.visitdate <= '".$_GET['to']."' 
                                    AND (" . implode(' OR ', $agen) . ")
                                    AND ch.customerowner like '$clienti' 
                                    AND ch.class like '$task' 
                                    AND ch.parentgroupname like '$categorie' 
                                    ") 
                                or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){ ?>
```

What can I do if `$agenti` has multiple values `(60 values)`. Values came from another file with `<select multiple="multiple"> <option value="test"> test </option>< /select>`

Comment: what you mean?  you mean $agenti is an array?

Comment: [Build SELECT query with dynamic number of LIKE conditions as a mysqli prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51036322/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$agenti` is dynamic array. Simple example :

```
$agen = array();

foreach ($agenti as $val) {
    $agen[] = "ch.employeename like '" . $val . "'"; 
}

$raw_results = mysql_query(
           "SELECT distinct ch.employeename, ch.customername, 
               ch.customerowner, ch.QuestionnaireName, ch.parentgroupname,
               ch.groupname, ch.visitdate from chestionare ch
            WHERE ch.visitdate >= '".$_GET['from']."' AND ch.visitdate <= '".$_GET['to']."' 
            AND (" . implode(' OR ', $agen) . ")
            AND ch.customerowner like '$clienti' 
            AND ch.class like '$task' 
            AND ch.parentgroupname like '$categorie' 
         ");
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: hi paul. can you help me with your script, it dosen't return results. i have modified the foreach like this: if(is_array($agenti)) { .... } but still nothing.

Comment: @rozatrra `if(is_array($agenti)) { .... } else {$agen[] = 'true';}` Should work fine

Comment: if i put the else condition, it returns all agents, i have update the script.

Comment: For the record, this is NOT a secure or stable querying script.  Do not use this in any real application (or even if you are just practicing).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `OR` like

if you meant $agenti is an array so it may be like this :

```
$agenti=array(John,Tommy,Mark);
```

which means this:

```
$agenti=array(
    0=>John,1=>Tommy,2=>Mark
);
```

so you should point to its elements like `$agenti[0]`

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT distinct ch.employeename, ch.customername, ch.customerowner, ch.QuestionnaireName, ch.parentgroupname,
  ch.groupname, ch.visitdate from chestionare ch
   WHERE ch.visitdate >= '{$_GET['from']}' AND ch.visitdate <= '{$_GET['to']}' 
    AND (
         ch.employeename like '{$agenti[0]}' 
         OR ch.employeename like '{$agenti[1]}' 
         OR ch.employeename like '{$agenti[2]}' 
    )
    AND ch.customerowner like '{$clienti}' 
    AND ch.class like '{$task}' 
    AND ch.parentgroupname like '{$categorie}' 
 ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: thx, but i keep agenti(employees) in another file with select multiple option and there are 60 of them.

Comment: @rozatrra - if Paul's answer is what you were looking for maybe you should accept it. (-:

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
            $agenti = array('sam','robin','sugar');
            $qry = "SELECT distinct ch.employeename, ch.customername, 
                     ch.customerowner, ch.QuestionnaireName, ch.parentgroupname,
                      ch.groupname, ch.visitdate from chestionare ch
                    WHERE ch.visitdate >= '".$_GET['from']."' AND ch.visitdate <= '".$_GET['to']."' 
                    AND ch.employeename IN('".implode("','",$agenti)."')  
                    AND ch.customerowner 
                    AND ch.class like '$task' 
                    AND ch.parentgroupname like '$categorie'
                                    ";

            /* Always use this way so it becomes easier for you to echo the query*/                         
            $raw_results = mysql_query($qry);
?>
```

Comment: please complete your answer and make it reach with an example and I would put you a +1.

Comment: ok here is +1 and I have also edited your answer adding description and links.

Comment: @ Jignesh Rawal - please add some description of what the new code does and how the `IN` Clause works.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in. Use the link to get it further cleared up.

Comment: you know you can edit your post to add the link and the description and also the php close (`?>`) tag is not seen as a code try to put some spaces before it.

Comment: done with the closing tag the link is given in the comment section :)

Comment: @imsiso there will be many that i will learn from you as well. Gd luck