# Dynamic parameter binding using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, eval, bindparam

In building prepared statements for my site, I found that a lot of redundant code could be iterated over. `mysqli::prepare` was a pretty straight forward one to iterate, but when I got to `mysqli::bind_param` and `mysqli::bind_result`, I ran into the following combination of issues:

1) I do not know how many parameters into `mysqli::bind_param`

2) Using `extract(Array)` into the arguments of `mysqli::bind_param` will not work, as the arguments for `mysqli::bind_param` are passed by reference
3) The `EXTR_REF` flag on `extract(Array)` won't help either, given that the value of the element passed cannot itself be a reference.

At this point, I've given up and am using `eval()`.

```
$statements[
    's_records_by_parent'=>[
        'sql'=>
            "select * from table where id=?",
        'params'=>[
                '"i"',
                '$id'
             ]
        ],
];
foreach($statements as $name=>$statement){
    if(!$name=$this->mysql->prepare(
        $statement['sql']
    ))
    {
        echo"Error preparing statement $name.";
        exit;
    }
    if(!eval("return \$name->bind_param(".implode(',',$statement['params']).");"))
    {
        echo"Error binding parameters for statement $name.";
        exit;
    }
}
```

The above code does exactly what I want it to do, with the exception of having an `eval()` statement which is ultimately going to be preparing statements based off of user input, which is concerning to me.

Comment: Have a look [how to dynamically bind parameters using prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010509/how-to-dynamically-bind-parameters-using-prepared-statement)

Comment: I'll try `call_user_func_array()` and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, that solved issue #1. The link you provided also shows how to create the references. Should have this one in a few minutes.

Comment: On a modern version of php you can do something like `bind_param(implode('', array_keys($params)), ...$params)`, see http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Comment: Ok, I have it working with `call_user_func_array()`. I'll post the final code.

Comment: This is why I use PDO instead of mysqli when I code in PHP. You can just pass your array of parameter values as an argument to [PDOStatement::execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). No need to do any binding. It's way easier for this kind of problem. Check out Examples #2 and #3 in the doc page I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code using `call_user_func_array()`:

```
$statements[
    's_records_by_parent'=>[
        'sql'=>
            "select * from table where id=?",
        'params'=>[
                'i',
                'id'
        ]
    ],
];
foreach($statements as $name=>&$statement){
    if(!$name=$this->mysql->prepare(
        $statement['sql']
    ))
    {
        echo"Error preparing statement $name.";
        exit;
    }
    foreach($statement['params']as$k=>$param)
         if($k)$statement['params'][$k]=&$$param;

    if(!call_user_func_array([$name,'bind_param'],$statement['params']))
    {
        echo"Error binding parameters for statement $name.";
        exit;
    }
}
```