# How to run multiple queries based on IF conditions?

Tags: php, sql, logic

I'm currently working on a mail system and I've hit a stump.

I want to make it so once I select a checkbox such as "Mail To Alphas", it mails it to all of the Alphas. And if I were to select "Mail to Alphas" *AND* "Mail to Betas", it should send it to Alphas and Betas, and so on... Unfortunately, it's only sending the e-mail to the last selected checkbox, which would be Deltas.

I've attempted to use the ".=" multi-query feature, but I didn't know exactly how to tame it with this structure of code.

Here's my code:

```
if ($mailAllCadets) {
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email,first_name,last_name FROM cadets ORDER BY id ASC");
}

if ($mailOneCadets) {
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email,first_name,last_name FROM cadets WHERE msl = '1' ORDER BY id ASC");
}

if ($mailTwoCadets) {
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email,first_name,last_name FROM cadets WHERE msl = '2' ORDER BY id ASC");
}

if ($mailThreeCadets) {
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email,first_name,last_name FROM cadets WHERE msl = '3' ORDER BY id ASC");
}

if ($mailFourCadets) {
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email,first_name,last_name FROM cadets WHERE msl = '4' ORDER BY id ASC");
}

if ($mailFiveCadets) {
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email,first_name,last_name FROM cadets WHERE msl = '5' ORDER BY id ASC");
}

$mailList = array(); // Create array containing recipients' e-mails.
$nameList = array(); // Create array containing the names of the recipients.

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
...
}
```

In plain text, this reads:

> If "Mail All Cadets" is selected, gather information on all cadets.
>
> If "Mail One Cadets" is selected, gather information on Level One cadets.
>
> ...
>
> If "Mail Five Cadets" is selected, gather information on Level Five cadets.

Obviously, the logic is severely failing here, as it only follows the last-given command. How can I make it so it concatenates these queries?

Comment: My advice: don't do it.  Restructure your script to grab everything that you need in one trip to the db.  If your momma told you to run to the shop and buy a dozen eggs and you made 12 trips to the shop -- she would speak to the neighbours about you being "different".

Comment: First of all, you can significantly reduce your code by wrapping from **$mailOneCadets** to **$mailFiveCadets** in one single line. `if ($mailAllCadets) { // do something } else { // here put your query for mailing cadets from one to five
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email,first_name,last_name FROM cadets WHERE msl = '${noOfCadets}' ORDER BY id ASC") }`

Comment: @mickmackusa I've thought about this approach. The only way I can think of doing it is, one `$result` query and an outside variable that concatenates a phrase such as "WHERE msl = ..." then echoing that variable into the one `$result` query. Just not sure how to execute it or if it would even work. I'll give it a go right now.

Comment: A conditional `WHERE msl IN ()` would be all that it takes.  You need to be using a prepared statement with bound parameters.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51036322/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa That worked perfectly. I'll post my solution. If you'd like to make this a reply, I'll note you as answered.

Comment: No one can post an answer as I have closed this question as a duplicate.  Stack Overflow wants to minimize the amount of redundant content on the site (despite the actions of many users).  I am happy that I could direct you to a working resolution.  I do not need any unicorn points.  You may elect to retract your question since it will likely be purged by the system in a few days anyhow.  Please do not edit your question to include your working solution -- this would push your question into the review queue and cause unnecessary work for volunteers.